# Xamarin.Android: Horizontal Scrollbar not working with SfPulltoRefresh

Tags: android-layout, xamarin.android, scrollbar, syncfusion

content_main.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:designer="http://xamarin.com/mono/android/designer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/placeholder"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="75px"
        android:id="@+id/city_txt" />
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/placeholder"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="50px"
        android:layout_below="@id/city_txt"
        android:id="@+id/date_txt" />
    ...
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollview_forcecast"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="false"
        android:layout_below="@id/info_layout">
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/placeholder"
                android:textSize="50px"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/forecast1" />
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/placeholder"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/forecast2"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/forecast1"/>
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/placeholder"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/forecast3" 
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/forecast2"/>
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/placeholder"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/forecast4"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/forecast3"/>
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/placeholder"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/forecast5"
                android:textSize="50px"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/forecast4"/>
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/placeholder"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/forecast6"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/forecast5"/>
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/placeholder"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/forecast7"
                android:textSize="50px"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/forecast6"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/placeholder"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/lastupdate_txt" />
    <Syncfusion.SfPullToRefresh.SfPullToRefresh 
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/sfPullToRefresh1"
    custom:transitionType="push"
    custom:progressStrokeColor="@android:color/black"
    custom:progressBackgroundColor="#ffffff"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

`<string name="placeholder>Placeholder</string>` 
If I push to App to my phone and try to swipe on the scrollbar literally nothing happens, I don't know If i need a function, or any other parameters, because I googled a lot and didnt find anything.
I am using Visual Studio 2019 with the Simple Template and Xamarin.Android.
You can see the Source Files here: https://github.com/kaaax0815/Weather.Xamarin \

#### Edit:

If I comment SfPulltoRefresh out, the ScrollView works fine. Is there a solution to use both of them?

Answer (score 0):

We have checked the sample in the Github https://github.com/kaaax0815/Weather.Xamarin/archive/v1.1.zip and we have modified the sample and added scrollview as SfPullToRefresh pullable content now vertical scrolling, horizontal scrolling and PullToRefresh is also working. We have also attached the tested sample and video for your reference.

Sample and video link : https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/Sample_and_video1312693410

Check the sample and revert us if you need any further assistance on this.
Regards,
Pradeep Kumar B